# How to route custom objects in an embedded Flink Statefun module?

Tags: java, flink-statefun

I have an *embedded* module in Apache Flink Statefun 3.0 (customized the Greeter example) that consumes JSON serialized events. When trying to `route()` messages deserialized from the ingress, I get an exception that my custom type is not convertible to protobuf (yes, it isn't) -- but *should* it be? I mean I tried to go with the 3.x docs but did not find any restrictions about the type that is to be routed.

Any hints or pointers on this?

Thanks

```
// The custom type (Bean-style and all)
public final class Message {
  @JsonProperty private String name;
  @JsonProperty private String id;
  @JsonProperty private int visits;
  public Message() {}
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String s) { name = s; }
  public String getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(String s) { id = s; }
  public int getVisits() { return visits; }
  public void setVisits(int i) { visits = i; }
}

// The function
public class GreeterFn implements StatefulFunction {
    public static final FunctionType TYPE = new FunctionType("example", "greeter");
    @Override
    public void invoke(Context ctx, Object msg) {
        // I never get here
    }
}

// The module
public class EmbeddedModule implements StatefulFunctionModule {
    static final IngressIdentifier<Message> INGRESS = new IngressIdentifier<>(Message.class, "example", "names");

    private static final class MsgDeser implements KafkaIngressDeserializer<Message> {
        private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @Override
        public Message deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> input) {
            try { return mapper.readValue(new String(input.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Message.class); }
            catch (java.io.IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return null; 
        }
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, String> globalConfiguration, Binder binder) {
        binder.bindIngress(KafkaIngressBuilder.forIdentifier(INGRESS)
            .withKafkaAddress("kafka:9092")
            .withTopic("names")
            .withDeserializer(MsgDeser.class)
            .withConsumerGroupId("my-group-id")
            .build());
        binder.bindIngressRouter(INGRESS, new Router<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void route(Message m, Downstream<Message> ds) {
                ds.forward(GreeterFn.TYPE, m.getName(), m); // <-- I get here OK but then the exception
            }
        });
        binder.bindFunctionProvider(GreeterFn.TYPE, x -> new GreeterFn());
    }
}

// And the logs (trimmed)
statefun-worker_1   | 2021-07-12 11:29:33,366 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Source: example-names-ingress -> router (names) (1/1)#0 (2b43e45ce4bcc61340ff131d147f3afe) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.         
statefun-worker_1   | java.lang.RuntimeException: class com.my.flink.Message cannot be cast to class com.google.protobuf.Message (com.my.flink.Message is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader @2aab3c1e; com.google.protobuf.Message is in unnamed module of loader 'app')                                                                                                                                                                                                  
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:103) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]                                                                                      
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:87) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]                                                                                                  
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:43) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]                                                                                                  
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]                                                                                                       
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]                                                                                                       
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.translation.IngressRouterOperator$DownstreamCollector.forward(IngressRouterOperator.java:127) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.0.0]                                                                
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.statefun.sdk.io.Router$Downstream.forward(Router.java:67) ~[statefun-flink-distribution.jar:3.0.0]                                                                                                                
statefun-worker_1   |   at com.my.flink.EmbeddedModule$1.route(EmbeddedModule.java:47) ~[myflink-1.jar:?]                                                                                                                                                 
statefun-worker_1   |   at com.my.flink.EmbeddedModule$1.route(EmbeddedModule.java:43) ~[myflink-1.jar:?]                                                                                                                                                 
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.translation.IngressRouterOperator.processElement(IngressRouterOperator.java:81) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.0.0]                                                                              
...
statefun-worker_1   | Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.my.flink.Message cannot be cast to class com.google.protobuf.Message (com.my.flink.Message is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader @2aab3c1e; com.google.protobuf.Message is in unnamed module of loader 'app')                                                                                                                                                                                     
statefun-worker_1   |   at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.message.MessagePayloadSerializerPb.serialize(MessagePayloadSerializerPb.java:50) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.0.0]                                                                             
...
```

Comment: hello there. do you know how to register statefun's `ValueSpec` in embedded module? when I was using remote http service, I was building `StatefulFunctionSpec` with all value specs inside, and was registering it by `StatefulFunctions.withStatefulFunction(spec)`, but cannot find the way of doing it with embedded module

Comment: I created a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75183735/flink-stateful-functions-how-to-register-statefuns-valuespec-in-embedded-modu so you may answer there if interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages that are sent/received by embedded functions are assumed to be Protobuf by default. You can use Kryo (or even a custom serializer) by setting, the following key in flink-conf.yaml:

> statefun.message.serializer: WITH_KRYO_PAYLOADS

This is not really recommend, as it will be difficult to evolve your application over time.

**You can still stick with Protobuf, by postponing the String -> Message deserialization by using a built in Protobuf type called StringValue.**

I've adopted the code you've pasted to use StringValue:

```
    public class EmbeddedModule implements StatefulFunctionModule {
    static final IngressIdentifier<StringValue> INGRESS = new IngressIdentifier<>(StringValue.class, "example", "names");


    private static final class MsgDeser implements KafkaIngressDeserializer<StringValue> {
        private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @Override
        public StringValue deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> input) {
            String json = new String(input.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            return StringValue.of(json);
        }
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, String> globalConfiguration, Binder binder) {
        binder.bindIngress(KafkaIngressBuilder.forIdentifier(INGRESS)
            .withKafkaAddress("kafka:9092")
            .withTopic("names")
            .withDeserializer(MsgDeser.class)
            .withConsumerGroupId("my-group-id")
            .build());
        binder.bindIngressRouter(INGRESS, new Router<StringValue>() {
            @Override
            public void route(StringValue m, Downstream<StringValue> ds) {
                String json = StringValue.getValue();
                String name = ... ; // extract the name from this JSON
                ds.forward(GreeterFn.TYPE, name , m);
            }
        });
        binder.bindFunctionProvider(GreeterFn.TYPE, x -> new GreeterFn());
    }
   }
```

**Define your Message as a Portobuf Message**

To avoid the double deserialization (both at the router and the function)
You can define the following Protobuf message:

```
message MyMessage {
 string name = 1;
 string id = 2;
 int visits = 3;
}
```

And then convert the json string to an instance of a MyMessage:

```
MyMessage.Builder builder = MyMessage.newBuilder();
JsonFormat.parser().merge(jsonString, builder);
MyMessage myMessage = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me where this part is documented, or only in code? "Messages ... are assumed to be Protobuf"

Comment: @user3607933 we need to document this a bit more clearly, but this is the result of having "statefun.message.serializer" set per job.

Comment: By "we" I get you're working on Flink -- cool stuff!